# Feedly - how do you make the left sidebar permanently show?

Tags: feedly

In the Chrome version of Feedly, the left sidebar auto-hides. I've spent the last 25 minutes attempting to make it stay open permanently (like it does in all the screenshots of Feedly), but I cannot. So every time I want to see something, esepcially in a nested folder, I need to manually move your mouse and click several times.

There must be something I'm missing >.<

Comment: This changed for me recently too. It looks like there's a button that says "PIN" on it at the top of the sidebar. I thought this had something to do with pinterest at first, but it does not.

Answer (score 5):

Maximize the width of your browser window.

I found your question when googling the same, and just found the answer on another site.  Worked for me in Chrome, but I had to maximize it ALL the way, not just close.

Comment: This is no longer the case. I have Feedly Beta (v. 14.0.484), installed on an OSX Chrome (v. 26.0.1410.65). It used to be there for the first week or so. But the left navigation has since, somehow disappeared, and maximizing the width of my browser window doesn't change that. Is there something I'm missing? I'd prefre to use Feedly. But not if it's fubar'd like this. I'm using ***[The Old Reader](http://theoldreader.com/)*** in the interim. Imports ***Reader*** data, and displays like a charm. Any help is welcome.

Comment: On their feature tracker they say the sidebar shows only > 1300px of width. http://feedly.uservoice.com/forums/192636-suggestions/suggestions/3746511-add-an-option-to-make-the-left-sidebar-sticky-i-

Answer (score 5):

There is now a button at the bottom of the navigation bar. Due to dark mode, it took me a little bit of time to find this. But pinning is handy when on a laptop.

[image: Feedly pin button]

Comment: This has been bugging me for a week!  Finally saw the tiny pin icon thanks to this.

Comment: This works, without having to depend on browser window width or font size.

Answer (score 2):

I found out by accident that zooming out/making the text smaller is the solution. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> on Mac) key whilst viewing the page in your browser. The sidebar auto-hide will now stop.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous comments, it seems that the navigation panel will automatically stay pinned or unpinned depending on the amount of space available to show the main panel. So depending on the size of your display font, your screen resolution, the width of your browser window etc., the pane will remain pinned or unpinned.

My suggestions are:

1. Reduce the size of your display font in the browser.
2. Increase the width of your browser window.